# Grid layout inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistackview

[image]

I am trying to make uitableview like the image below but i am unable to insert time label. i tried using uicollectionview  inside uitableview but was not like that and also tried uistackview but failed.

Comment: I would drop the tableView and use a collectionView for this with a flowLayout. Using a tableView with cells, with in these cells collectionViews will make your code overly complex, as you have to do different height calculations for your cells.

Comment: ok i will use collection view but the above time label comes from server and is dynamic how to configure that in collection view cell, uistackview grows in one direction either horizontal or vertical but i want it grid like above